# If Google Play Store is hidden, Google Play Service is not available too

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, adb

I am working on MDM application. We need to hide the Google Play Store from list of apps. Also, Google Play Services is required for fetching the current location of the device.

I hide the google play store using the following command

```
adb shell pm hide com.android.vending
```

I un-hide the google play service using the following command

```
adb shell pm unhide com.google.android.gms
```

The google play service is still not available. I get the Update Google Play Services dialog. Since google Play store is hidden, we cannot launch the store to update the missing service.

Is it possible to hide google play store without affecting google play services? I do not want to block the store but hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are being an EMM on Android instead of hiding Google Play, you should work with it. Try using their [EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/).